# highcharts polar series on then off then on

Tags: highcharts, axis-labels, polar-coordinates

I've got a highcharts polar/line graph being driven by an HTML table. It works fine when initially displayed. Then I can click on the series in the legend/key area to turn off the series. So far, so good. But then if I click on the legend again to turn the series back on, I have a problem. It appears that the graph line comes and goes correctly, but the spoke labels are off by one. If I start with 5 spokes, turn the series off then back on, I get 6 spoke labels (but actually the 5 spokes themselves are fine).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
$('#content_Result').highcharts({
data: {
table: 'datatable',
startRow: 1,
endRow: 6,
endColumn: 1,
},
chart: {
polar: true,
type: 'line'
},
title: {
text: 'my Title',
x: -1
},
yAxis: {
min: 0,
endOnTick: false,
showLastLabel: true,
reversedStacks: false
},
legend: {
layout: 'vertical',
align: 'right',
verticalAlign: 'middle',
borderWidth: 0
}
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="content_Result" style="min-width: 1200px; max-width: 1200px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
<table id="datatable" class="RadarIndicatorTable">
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Title</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>SF</th>
<th>Current</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Spoke 1</td>
<td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Spoke 2</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Spoke 3</td>
<td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Spoke 4</td>
<td>73.52</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Spoke 4</td>
<td>50</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've made jsfiddle. But I cannot see any weirdness there. Can you refer to that fiddle?

Comment: @morganfree you can see the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/oshe114e/ on load, there are 5 y axis gridlines. Hide the series via the legend and then show again, there are 6.

Comment: I am only seeing 4 yAxis lines at 25, 50, 75, and 100. Toggling series off then on still shows 4. The outside blue-ish ring is your xAxis.

Comment: When I try @jlbriggs fiddle, I'm seeing the same results as wergeld saw. I would point out that while there are consistently FOUR labels, there are 5 data points. And, I'm seeing the labels as Jan 01, Feb 01 .... Rather than Spoke 1, Spoke 2 ....

Comment: @wergeld Sorry, yes, I meant x axis grid lines, or as OP called them, the "spokes"

Comment: OK, Now I'm really confused. I created my own fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rpflughoeft/L5donhdL/16/ and when I run that in Chrome, I get the results that @wergeld saw. But if I run it with Microsoft Edge, I get the results I originally posted.

So there sure the browser type is a factor -AND- JSFiddle works a little different than my base page.

Comment: Yea, for xAxis "spokes" I still only see 5 in Chrome. Under IE I see 5..then 6 after toggle. But, also, the labels are different under IE or Chrome for same jsfiddle code. Chrome has the dates on the spoke lines whereas IE has "Spoke N" in the middle of the category spoke. Very, very strange.

Comment: For me, Firefox starts with 5 spoke labels, then goes to 6.